# What is the difference between an empty constructor and no constructor

Tags: java

I'm moving from `PHP` to `Java` it's really hard to understand OOP as english is not my main language. I want a simple answer (as simple as possible, lol). Whats the difference between:

```
class Munikas {

    public Munikas(){
    }

    public void rytas(){
        System.out.println("Labas Rytas");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Munikas labas = new Munikas();
        labas.rytas();
    }
}
```

And

```
class Munikas {
    public void rytas(){
        System.out.println("Labas rytas");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Munikas labas = new Munikas();
        labas.rytas();
    }
}
```

On second I don't use `constructor`. How will it affect my code in future?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference between the snippets of code you've provided.  A user-supplied no-arg constructor is essentially the same as the default no-arg constructor which is supplied by Java by default.

If you did anything inside of that no-arg constructor, *then* there would be a difference, but as authored, these two code samples are equivalent.

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) provides more context to this, with a code sample similar to your own.

Comment: So I need to build constructor on my own only when I need to use args in it?

Comment: @TomasVilemaitis: Generally that is the use case for constructors, although you can use a constructor to establish some default state if you truly wanted to.

Comment: @TomasVilemaitis No. Only when you do something in constructor. There can be a constructor without arguments that sets some fields.

Comment: Thanks you for your time and answers! It helped me a lot.

Comment: is it the jvm or the compiler that provides the default c'tor?

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference. When your class doesn't define any constructor (as in your second snippet), the compiler will automatically insert a parameter-less constructor with an empty body, so the second snippet is equivalent to the first.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use the empty constructor. Compiler will generate it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

classes in java have default constructor that get created behind the scenes.  In the first one you added the constructor. the second one, java compiler will create a default constructor that is empty.

more info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

***Java constructors*** are special methods that are called when an object is instantiated using `new` keyword as:

`ClassName referenceName = new ClassName();`

***Default Constructor:***

`public ClassName(){ // no statements }`

Constructor in the class is not **must**. If you do not define the constructor in the class then **JVM** adds the **default** one.

***In the first code:***

You have defined the default constructor which doesn't have any statements so it does nothing. It's just like not defining the constructor.

***In the second code:***

**JVM** automatically defines the default constructor same as in your first code. So, there will not be any effect of not adding the constructor .

Answer (score 0):

An empty constructor is equivalent to providing no constructor but by setting an empty constructor you can specify which level of accessibility you want to set to the constructor itself regardless of what accessibility level your class has. As in the provided example if you want to prevent the initiation of the class, you have to set a private constructor.

This class is from an open source project https://github.com/openshopio/openshop.io-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/bf/io/openshop/api/EndPoints.java

```
package bf.io.openshop.api;

import bf.io.openshop.CONST;

public class EndPoints {

/**
 * Base server url.
 */
private static final String API_URL                  = "http://77.93.198.186/v1.2/";    // staging

public static final String SHOPS                    = API_URL.concat(CONST.ORGANIZATION_ID + "/shops");
public static final String SHOPS_SINGLE             = API_URL.concat(CONST.ORGANIZATION_ID + "/shops/%d");
public static final String NAVIGATION_DRAWER        = API_URL.concat("%d/navigation_drawer");
public static final String BANNERS                  = API_URL.concat("%d/banners");
public static final String PAGES_SINGLE             = API_URL.concat("%d/pages/%d");
public static final String PAGES_TERMS_AND_COND     = API_URL.concat("%d/pages/terms");
public static final String PRODUCTS                 = API_URL.concat("%d/products");
public static final String PRODUCTS_SINGLE          = API_URL.concat("%d/products/%d");
public static final String PRODUCTS_SINGLE_RELATED  = API_URL.concat("%d/products/%d?include=related");
public static final String USER_REGISTER            = API_URL.concat("%d/users/register");
public static final String USER_LOGIN_EMAIL         = API_URL.concat("%d/login/email");
public static final String USER_LOGIN_FACEBOOK      = API_URL.concat("%d/login/facebook");
public static final String USER_RESET_PASSWORD      = API_URL.concat("%d/users/reset-password");
public static final String USER_SINGLE              = API_URL.concat("%d/users/%d");
public static final String USER_CHANGE_PASSWORD     = API_URL.concat("%d/users/%d/password");
public static final String CART                     = API_URL.concat("%d/cart");
public static final String CART_INFO                = API_URL.concat("%d/cart/info");
public static final String CART_ITEM                = API_URL.concat("%d/cart/%d");
public static final String CART_DELIVERY_INFO       = API_URL.concat("%d/cart/delivery-info");
public static final String CART_DISCOUNTS           = API_URL.concat("%d/cart/discounts");
public static final String CART_DISCOUNTS_SINGLE    = API_URL.concat("%d/cart/discounts/%d");
public static final String ORDERS                   = API_URL.concat("%d/orders");
public static final String ORDERS_SINGLE            = API_URL.concat("%d/orders/%d");
public static final String BRANCHES                 = API_URL.concat("%d/branches");
public static final String WISHLIST                 = API_URL.concat("%d/wishlist");
public static final String WISHLIST_SINGLE          = API_URL.concat("%d/wishlist/%d");
public static final String WISHLIST_IS_IN_WISHLIST  = API_URL.concat("%d/wishlist/is-in-wishlist/%d");
public static final String REGISTER_NOTIFICATION    = API_URL.concat("%d/devices");


// Notifications parameters
public static final String NOTIFICATION_LINK        = "link";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE     = "message";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_TITLE       = "title";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_IMAGE_URL   = "image_url";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_SHOP_ID     = "shop_id";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_UTM         = "utm";

/// Empty constructor is equivalent to providing no constructor
/// but if you want to prevent the initiation of the class then you have to set a private constructor.
private EndPoints() {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply speaking, the constructor allows you to create an instance object of your class, using something like this:

```
Munikas testObject = new Munikas();
```

The difference between the two will be evident when you try to use NON-STATIC methods. The method rytas() is non-static, which means that you need to call it using an instantiated object of the class, like so:

```
testObject.rytas();
```

So when using rytas, you will need to use a constructor. As other people have mentioned, you do not need to add code to create the empty constructor, however sometimes you will need to use constructors for objects with parameters. The main STATIC method will be fine with or without a constructor and can be called using just the class (Munikas) itself. For more information, check [this](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-vs-non-static-methods/) out. Hope that helps.